# crypto.getCiphers() - Why are a different set of algorithms available via NodeJS (v12.18.3) versus ElectronJS via (NodeJS 12.14.1)?

Tags: node.js, openssl, electron

Take a look at the NodeJS documentation for version 12.18.3 for the `crypto.createCipheriv()` [method](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options).

The method takes 3 required params:

1. `algorithm` (string representing algo used to encrypt data)
2. `key` (string or buffer representing "password" for encryption)
3. `iv` (string or buffer representing initialization vector)

**Algorithm String**

The site also explains that the values for the Algorithm string can be obtained by running a terminal command : `$ openssl list -cipher-algorithms`

Unfortunately, there is no other documentation about the string values for algorithm parameter at the site.

**List of 175 Algorithms Available on My Machine**

So far, all is good.  I ran the terminal command and I get a list of 175 encryption algorithms that are available.
They look something like the following:

```
AES-128-CBC
AES-128-CBC-HMAC-SHA1
AES-128-CBC-HMAC-SHA256
id-aes128-CCM
AES-128-CFB
AES-128-CFB1
AES-128-CFB8
AES-128-CTR
AES-128-ECB
id-aes128-GCM
AES-128-OCB
AES-128-OFB
AES-128-XTS
AES-192-CBC
id-aes192-CCM
AES-192-CFB
AES-192-CFB1
AES-192-CFB8
AES-192-CTR
AES-192-ECB
id-aes192-GCM
AES-192-OCB
AES-192-OFB
AES-256-CBC
...
```

**Node v12.18.3**

When I set up the appropriate items and run another NodeJS crypto algorithm from a sample app called `crypto.getCiphers()` I see the exact same list of 175 algorithms.
This runs with the default Node version on my machine v12.18.3.

**Node Under Electron : v12.14.1**

However, when I call that same method from within my ElectonJS app running Node v12.14.1 and Electron 9.3.0, I only see 24 algorithms listed.

**No Documentation and No Explanation to the Difference**

However, there is no documentation that this slightly different version of Node would return anything different than the list that is available on my machine.

**Questions**

Why does Node v12.14.1 via Electron only give me the list of 24?  Where is that list coming from?  Can anyone show me where that might be documented?

Here's a snapshot of the Electron app displaying the versions and displaying the call to crypto.getCiphers():

[image: electron and crypto.getCiphers()]

This problem became apparent when I could [*run official Node example code](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/cryptography/how-to-use-crypto-module/) using the algorithm string "aes256" via node v12.18.3 but could not run the code via electron / node v12.4.1, because the "aes256" algorithm wasn't available.
That sample code includes the following line : `crypto.createCipheriv("aes256", key, resizedIV)`

**Update**

Had to come back and add the following as part of this question.
I successfully got the data encrypted using the appropriate algorithm (aes-256-cbc) and now as I'm decrypting the data in my ElectronJS app I get the following error:

[image: openssl reference]

My point here is that the error that shows up references OPENSSL from within the ElectronJS app, even though (most likely - from posted comment) Electron actually uses BoringSSL.  I suppose to understand this stuff you have to be a Rocket Scientist *and* a Brain Surgeon.  xD

Comment: I'd guess because electron [uses boringssl not openssl](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23347#issuecomment-639051311).

Comment: Wow! That probably is the answer.  But how would I ever have known that?  It's so weird because I'm expecting an API from Node, but then under that there is something else.  Wow, i'm just knocked out by this.  Thanks - Also if you write that up as an answer I'll mark it as solution.  May be helpful to someone in the future.